# How to send message after NSArrayController did automatically rearrange it's objects?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview, nsarraycontroller

I did enable `automaticallyRearrangesObjects` in my `NSArrayController`.

This works fine, but i would like to send `-scrollRowToVisible` to the related `NSTableView` each time the `NSArrayController` rearranged, so that the currently selected row stays always visible.

Where could i put this, so that it get's sent at each rearrangement?

Comment: Would listening for `didChangeArrangementCriteria` be sufficient?

Comment: Unfortunately not, because the NSArrayController also rearranges after new items are inserted, or when the attributes of an item, that are relevant for sorting, change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use KVO to observe the array controller's `arrangedObjects` property. When that changes, you can scroll.

(For what it's worth, this may annoy your users if they have deliberately scrolled to view another part of the table.)

Comment: Works well, and you are right with your remark about the fact that users could have deliberately scrolled elsewhere.